# Spring MVC Interceptor does not exclude provided URLs

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I want to make an interceptor that will intercept every request except a few ones. The problem that I have is the interceptor still intercepts the requests that I provided with exclude-mapping. I tried all sorts of variations but nothing worked. Here is the configuration

```
<mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/checkout/campaign/**"/>
            <bean class="com.package.package.package.package.package.CampaignBeforeControllerHandler" >
                <-- list of services  -->
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
```

And here is an actual request: `https://localhost:9002/checkout/campaign/test`  . In my opnion the pattern matches this request so it should be excluded but it is not, I still get into the class of the interceptor. Is the pattern that I provided somehow bad?

EDIT: I am using Spring MVC 3.2.8

Comment: which spring version are you using?

Comment: Spring mvc 3.2.8.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have adding 'mvc' to inner elements that causes

[Doc example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors)

```
<mvc:interceptors>
            <mvc:interceptor>
                <mapping path="/**"/>
                <exclude-mapping path="/checkout/campaign/**"/>
                <bean class="com.package.package.package.package.package.CampaignBeforeControllerHandler" >
                    <-- list of services  -->
                </bean>
            </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```